# Schema-less indexing search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-ruby

I have a set of data following a similar data structure below:

```
{
    "first_name": "some_value",
    "last_name": "some_value_2",
    "instance": "some_instance"
    "num_of_tries": 159,
    "uuid": "some_uuid",
    "background": "something the user can input anything that want here"
    ... more data ...
}
```

I have a schema-less index using the standard analyzer (no custom mappings).

I pull data from `A` server that has 52 records.  It gets indexed into the index successfully.  I then do a match search against the index using the `instance` field (say, `"ins55"`).  All 52 records come back as expected that match this `instance` value.  I can also see 52 docs, as expected.

I then add another 198 records from `B` server.  It gets indexed into the index successfully.  I can see that there are now 250 docs, as expected in the index.  I then do match search against the index using the `instance` field that matches the data from the `A` server (the `"ins55"`).  Only 22 records come back out of the 52 records that were expected.

Can someone give me some insight into why all 250 docs are listed in the index, but it's not returning the expected number of records for the match?

Comment: What kind of document ID are you using? custom ones or auto-generated ones?

Comment: I am using the auto generated one.  There are no settings setup for this index.  It’s basically a default generated index.

Comment: So auto generated ones to answer the question.

Comment: ok, how do you populate your index (custom client code, Logstash, etc)? Can you show some code?

Comment: Yeah.  Right now I’m using Ruby gem to handle adding new items to index on a schedule through a rake task.  The “elasticsearch-persistence” gem.

Comment: Sorry, I have been on holiday.  So, looking at the backend code, it's just doing a normal PUT to put stuff into elastic.  Nothing special is going on with the PUT.